# How can I figure out why my Java application keeps on running after exit?

Tags: java, winapi, launch4j

I'm developing a Java desktop application for Windows and I'm trying to implement the Windows Restart Manager. I'm successfully receiving the Windows messages for exiting the application and when I send them manually, it just works and the application shut downs.

When I do it as part of the uninstall process, the shutdown procedure in my application runs and I can even see it calls `System.exit(0)` but even after that, there's a process that doesn't stop. My Java application is packaged into an executable file using launch4j in case that's relevant.

The way I know `System.exit(0)` is being called is because I'm dumping debugging information to a file and I print out that `System.exit(0)` is about to be call and I can see that whether the application succeeds or fails on properly shutting down.

Using the Process Explorer I can see the `javaw.exe` sub-process and when the exit procedure happens, that goes away, but the parent process remains. While the is running, it looks like this:

[image]

and after the failed exit, it looks like this:

[image]

If I have a remote debugger connected to the process, at this point, the debugger gets disconnected.

What could be causing this?

I'm close to being convinced this is a bug in launch4j, so, I reported it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/185/